buildError: EPERM: operation not permitted during packaging VS Code extension
I'm working on developing a VS Code extension, and while packaging the extension using npm in a Windows environment, I encountered the following error:
Executing task: node D:\test_dev\pilot/extensions/vscode/scripts/prepac
[info] Using target:  win32-x64
[info] Packaging extension for target  win32-x64
[info] npm install in extensions/vscode completed
[info] npm install in gui completed
[info] Copied gui build to JetBrains extension
Copied gui build to VSCode extension
[info] Copied onnxruntime-node
[info] Copied tree-sitter.wasm
[info] Copied llamaTokenizerWorkerPool.mjs
[info] Copied llamaTokenizer.mjs
[info] Copied tiktokenWorkerPool.mjs
npm installing esbuild binary
Copying esbuild@0.17.19 to @esbuild
node:fs:1885
  binding.unlink(path);
          ^
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\test_dev\pilot\extensions2-x64\esbuild.exe'


It seems like there's an issue with permissions when trying to unlink esbuild.exe. I've tried running the command as an administrator, but the problem persists.
What could be causing this "operation not permitted" error when trying to unlink esbuild.exe?
Are there any specific permissions or settings that need to be adjusted for this to work on Windows?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
